# Italic index entries have no link in PDF

Tags: hyperref, indexing, italic

I have a problem when adding index entries. When I use just the vanilla `\index{...}`, the generated PDF contains links on the page numbers in the index. But when using `\index{...|textit}` to mark index entries as primary entries, these links disappear. The same happens when I use `textbf` instead of `textit`.

I looked through the documentation of `makeidx` and `hyperref`, but didn't find any reference to that problem there.

Here is a minimal example. I used `latexmk -pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Text. \index{normal} \index{bold|textbf} \index{italic|textit}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This is my TeX version:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 
(TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2011.5.25)
```

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. You should load **makeidx** before **hyperref**, but actually doesn't make any difference in the output

Comment: Hmm, I just compiled it on http://www.scribtex.com, and the linking works! Maybe it's a version problem?

Comment: That might be. Add a `\listfiles` command to the sample and compare the results you get in the log file.

Comment: I installed the latest texlive (20110724), and now my example works, but my original document still has the same problem. Still investigating..

Comment: OK, it looks like it's the memoir document class that's causing the problem. I changed my docuemtn to use the book class, and now the links work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. When looking at the .ind file produced by makeindex, the entries looked like this:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \item Principal entry, \textit{14}
  \indexspace
  \item Normal entry, \hyperpage{30}
\end{theindex}
```

This was because I used `\index{Principal entry|textit}` in my file. I solved it by defining a command that uses textit and hyperpage:

```
\newcommand{\boldindex}[1]{\textit{\hyperpage{#1}}}
```

And then using `\index{Principal entry|boldindex}` to index terms.

This is even explained in the README file of the hyperref package, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/.

Comment: Now don't start convincing me to read those README files.