# \index produces invalid .idx entry (with manual style, \comma@parse, hyperref)

Tags: hyperref, indexing

*(Note:  This is somewhat related [similar post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23785/36201), but the issue is quite different.)*

I'm trying to make an index entry using `\index` that has a bolded page number, all while the `hyperref` package is loaded. Normally when hyperref sees a manually-inserted `|textbf` in an index entry it will do something clever like modify or remove the usual `|hyperpage` insertion. That's fine. No problem.

The trouble lies when I try to first parse argument of `\index` using the macro `\comma@parse` from the [`kvsetkeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kvsetkeys) package, as shown here:

```
%with hyperref is loaded, this produces a bad .idx entry
\comma@parse{But this fails on makeindex|textbf}{\index{\comma@entry}\@gobble}
```

The code above produces the following entry in the .idx file:

```
\indexentry{But this fails on makeindex|textbf|hyperpage}{1}
```

As you can see, there are two `|` symbols in the entry, causing the `makeindex` to reject it. `hyperref` should have caught this.

- If I disable hyperref, everything works fine.
- If I don't use the `\comma@parse` macro, everything works fine.
- The same thing happens if instead of `|textbf` I do `|see` etc.

It's as if using `\comma@parse` doesn't allow `hyperref` to do its job.

**Is there a way I can get the `.idx` entry to be well-formed while keeping hyperref loaded?**

Here's the MWE I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\index{1@This works fine|textbf}
\makeatletter
    \comma@parse{2@So does this}{\index{\comma@entry}\@gobble}
    \comma@parse{3@But this fails on makeindex|textbf}{\index{\comma@entry}\@gobble}
\makeatother

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And here's the `.idx` file that is created after typesetting:

```
\indexentry{This works fine|hyperindexformat{\textbf}}{1}
\indexentry{So does this|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{But this fails on makeindex|textbf|hyperpage}{1}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|` is hidden by macro `\comma@entry`. Therefore `hyperref` does not see it, when it appends `|hyperpage` for hyper-linked page numbers in the index.
`\expandafter` helps:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\index{This works fine|textbf}%
\makeatletter
    \comma@parse{So does this}{\index{\comma@entry}\@gobble}%
    \comma@parse{This also works|textbf}{%
      \expandafter\index\expandafter{\comma@entry}\@gobble 
    }%
\makeatother

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Or much easier, `\index` is already used as command that takes an entry, thus it can be directly used as comma list processor:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\index{This works fine|textbf}%
\makeatletter
    \comma@parse{So does this}\index
    \comma@parse{This also works|textbf}\index
\makeatother

\printindex

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Package `splitidx`

The trick of the previous example also works for commands with additional argument, if they precede the argument, which gets the list entry:

```
\comma@parse{my, comma, list}{\sindex[...]}
```

A macro `\idxboldpage` can be defined to get hyperlinked bold page numbers,
as `\sindex` of package `splitidx` is not automatically supported by `hyperref`:

```
\newcommand*{\idxboldpage}[1]{%
  \textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}%
}
```

Then `\index{...|idxboldpage}` is used instead of `\index{...|textbf}`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}
\newindex[Author index]{authidx}
\newcommand*{\idxboldpage}[1]{%
  \textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\index{This works fine|textbf}%
\makeatletter
    \comma@parse{So does this}{\sindex[authidx]}
    \comma@parse{This also works|idxboldpage}{\sindex[authidx]}
\makeatother

\printindex[authidx]

\end{document}
```

Comment: My mouth dropped when I saw that second solution. Thank you. I think I still have some more learning to understand why you can put `\index` like that without an explicit `{}` argument. FYI modified index entries with `1@` etc.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for using `\sindex[]{}` from the [`splitidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/splitindex) package? Neither works; I'm using `\sindex[]` where I would put `\index`. Should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: @BMS It's the way `\comma@parse` works. It has two interfaces. In the first example `\comma@entry` is defined and can be used by the comma list processor. Also the comma list processor gets the entry in curly braces as argument. Therefore `\index` as comma list processor sees the entry as argument.

Comment: @BMS The important issue is that `|` is not hidden in a macro, when `hyperref`'s index macros are used.